# How to convert string to char* without losing data in c++

Tags: c++, string, char

I have wanted to return char*. But my code is like that:

```
something.str() --> it is returning string
 (in stringstream --> string str() const;)
```

I want to do that return `char*` as strstream does.

```
(strstream -->char* str();)
```

I am converting my codes to sstream and how can I do?

Comment: you can call `c_str()` on `str()` to return a `char *` so `something.str().c_str()` should work as `str()` returns a [`std::basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think printStream->str() is returning a string object with a copy (temporary) of the contents.then you are invoking c_str() on it and getting a const char *, and then casting away the const-ness, and then returning the pointer outside the function scope.  I think since its a temporary value you are getting back from printStream->str(), you will be using a pointer to deallocated memory outside this function.

Comment: Sorry what are you intending to do with the `char *`? Your question lacks context

Comment: my other functions need char * returning.i dont want to fix them morely

Comment: General answer: Analyze your situation, understand your problem, deploy the right tools. "Conversions" like this are almost never a matter of a simple search/replace. You need to figure out the right components and lifetimes and all that that make up the new idiom.

Comment: tried that but is it appropriate.i want to be sure. const_cast<char *>(printStream->str().c_str());

Comment: @FikriUzun again, `str()` returns a **TEMPORARY** string that is freed after the entire statement is finished, and you are not saving the string anywhere, so the retrieved `char*` is **USELESS** before you have a chance to even use it. You **MUST** save the string somewhere so it outlives your use of the `char*`, thus ensuring the `char*` remains pointing at valid memory. Otherwise, rethink your design.